# How could take the auto-completion in a vim decent way?

Tags: vim

I tried to select the auto-complete

[image]

Have to press down-arrow to select the hints.

How could I take the auto-completion in a vim decent way?

Answer (score 3):

That behavior is controlled by the [`'completeopt'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27completeopt%27) option. Based on your screenshot, you seem to have `menuone` and `noselect` in there. With the default value (`menu,preview`), this should work as you expect.